# Vector norm of an array of vectors in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vectorization, normalization

When calling [`norm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/norm.html) on a matrix in MATLAB, it returns what's known as a "matrix norm" (a scalar value), instead of an array of vector norms. Is there any way to obtain the norm of each vector in a matrix without looping and taking advantage of MATLAB's vectorization?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can compute the norm of each column or row of a matrix yourself by using [element-wise arithmetic operators](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arithmeticoperators.html) and functions defined to operate over given matrix dimensions (like [SUM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sum.html) and [MAX](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/max.html)). Here's how you could compute some column-wise norms for a matrix `M`:

```
twoNorm = sqrt(sum(abs(M).^2,1)); %# The two-norm of each column
pNorm = sum(abs(M).^p,1).^(1/p);  %# The p-norm of each column (define p first)
infNorm = max(M,[],1);            %# The infinity norm (max value) of each column
```

These norms can easily be made to operate on the rows instead of the columns by changing the dimension arguments from `...,1` to `...,2`.

Comment: maybe you should explicitly specify the dimensions along which SUM and MAX operate, that way it would be easier to switch to row-wise norms...

Comment: If `M` consists of real numbers only, you can replace the `abs(M)` with `M` in the `twoNorm` as the `.^2` effectively cancels out any negative signs.

Comment: If M contains any non-real number, you may want to M.*conj(M) instead

Comment: For the two-norm you can also use `sqrt(dot(M, M, dim))`.

Answer (score 8):

From version 2017b onwards, you can use [vecnorm](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vecnorm.html).

Answer (score 4):

The existing implementation for the two-norm can be improved.

```
twoNorm = sqrt(sum(abs(M).^2,1)); # The two-norm of each column
```

`abs(M).^2` is going to be calculating a whole bunch of unnecessary square roots which just get squared straightaway.

Far better to do:

```
twoNorm = sqrt( 
               sum( real(M .* conj(M)),  1 )
              )
```

This efficiently handles real and complex M.

Using `real()` ensures that `sum` and `sqrt` act over real numbers (rather than complex numbers with 0 imaginary component).

Comment: Slight addition:  `norm_2 = @(A,dim)sqrt( sum( real(A).*conj(A) , dim) )`  allows for `B=magic([2,3])` and `norm_2( B , 1) ` or `norm_2( B , 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Slight addition to [P i's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40440075/1200764):

```
norm_2 = @(A,dim)sqrt( sum( real(A).*conj(A) , dim) )
```

allows for

```
B=magic([2,3])
norm_2( B , 1)
norm_2( B , 2)
```

or as this if you want a norm_2.m file:

```
function norm_2__ = norm_2 (A_,dim_)
    norm_2__ = sqrt( sum( real(A_).*conj(A_) , dim_) )  ;
end
```