# applying norm function to rows of matrix - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a 3 columns, n rows matrix:

```
[ a,b,c;
  d,e,f;
  g,h,i; ]
```

I want to apply the norm function to each of the rows, and get a `1xn` matrix containing the norms:

```
[ norm([a,b,c]);
  norm([d,e,f]);
  norm([g,h,i]); ]
```

I could do this with a for-loop, but is there a better way?

Comment: actually that is a problem of mine too. In my case I have to evaluate the norm of position of particles whose coordinates are in the rows of the matrix. What I usually do is: `norms = sqrt(A(:,1).^2 + A(:,2).^2 + A(:,3).^2)`. But I strongly suspect the existence of a cleverer way ;).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

What about

```
 norms = sqrt(sum(A.^2,1))
```

or

```
 norms = sqrt(sum(A.^2,2))?
```

depending on whether your coordinates are in rows or in columns.

Comment: you mean "coordinates are in columns or rows". sum(...,1) adds up down each column and sum(...,2) adds up across each row.

Comment: Inline func, with the option of which dimension to norm along:  `norm_2 = @(A,dim)sqrt( sum( real(A).*conj(A) , dim) )`  allows for `B=magic([2,3])` --> `norm_2( B , 1) ` or `norm_2( B , 2)`.   See also  [P i's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40440075/1200764).

Comment: shouldn't it be `norms = sqrt.(...` (mind the dot after sqrt-function)

Answer (score 3):

If readability is a bigger consideration than performance you might also consider:

```
norms = cellfun(@norm,num2cell(A,2));
```

This pattern is also adaptable to other operations along one dimension you might want to perform where MATLAB doesn't support it natively.

Answer (score 2):

if the first dimension is not too large:

```
norms = sqrt(diag(A * A'));
```

Comment: It looks to me that you always have to face the larger dimension, I mean, in order to be useful `A*A'` must always return a `n x n` matrix. That would give you a lot of overhead, though.

Comment: yes, the result of `A * A'` is nxn.

Comment: Code is supposed to be fun to read, right? :P